# Redundant attributes in multiple Java classes

Tags: java, class

Say I have a super-class and multiple sub-classes of that class. Now I want the sub-classes to all have a static attribute with the same name. If I give the super-class such an attribute (static) and change this inherited attribute in one of the sub-classes, it also gets changed for all of the other sub-classes.

Is it possible to have a "static" attribute only for the sub-classes (somehow inherited from the super-class so that the attribute wouldn't be redundant and would not have to be declared in each of the sub-classes)? Or is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Exactly as you've described? No, that's not possible. Can you show us what you want a bit more concretely? There is most likely a better solution to this problem. Non-final static variables are very commonly misused, and it sounds like you're misusing them. We can try to help you, but we'll need to see some of the code.

Comment: Describe the problem that gave you that idea.

Comment: Instead of having two seperate static attributes in sub-classes like: `class Sub1 extends Super { private static name; }` and `class Sub2 extends Super { private static name; }`, is it somehow possible to inherit such static attributes? Else it would be redundant to declare these multiple times.

Comment: if the 2 names are not the same... maybe you should not make the field static.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I can find is that you add a method to the super class that returns the value for most of the sub classes.

Then, you can override that method on each sub class that has a different returning value.

```
class Parent {
    public String getType() {
        return "A";
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
    public String getType() {
        return "B";
    }
}
```